# How to extract and remove in pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to remove words in column1 if they appear in column2.

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| word1 word2 | word1 |
| word1 |  |

I want

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| word2 | word1 |
| word1 |  |

I tried this but doesn't word.

```
df['col1'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: x['col1'].replace(x['col2'],''))
```

Comment: Should we replace word like `mousepad` to `pad` if `mouse` appear in `column2` ?  If no, we need to handle for word boundary.

Comment: No, I don't want to consider subword. The solution below does the job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `axis=1` pro processing per rows with `strip` for remove traling spaces:

```
df['col1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col1'].replace(x['col2'],'').strip(), axis=1)
```